# Eigen: Get scalar type from array type is documented?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I want to know if getting the scalar type from the array type by `ArrayType::Scalar` is documented for the Eigen library.

The following compiles (`g++ test.cpp -I<Path to Eigen> -frtti`)

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Eigen::ArrayXf::Scalar i = 0;
    std::cout << typeid(i).name() << "\n";
}
```

Result (float type as expected):

```
f
```

That also works for `MatrixXf` type.

Comment: Dense matrices inherit from `DenseBase` and this has a [public typedef `Scalar`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#pub-types).

Comment: It's not portable to sparse matrices though.  The public typedef in `SparseMatrixBase` is called [`value_type`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrixBase.html#pub-types) instead of `Scalar`.

Comment: @HenriMenke `SparseMatrix` also has a `Scalar` typedef. I'm not sure why it does not appear in the doxygen documentation. `value_type` was added later to add a bit of compatibility with `std` containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is documented by [doxygen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a5feed465b3a8e60c47e73ecce83e39a2), at least for `DenseBase`. I found it when I searched for "scalar" in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/

```
template<typename Derived>
typedef internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar Eigen::DenseBase< Derived >::Scalar
```

> The numeric type of the expression' coefficients, e.g. float, double,
>   int or std::complex, etc.

Comment: Hopefully that means `::Scalar` is part of the public api and it is safe to use it...

Comment: Yes it is part of the public and stable API!